# Is " const wchar_t* " a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, wchar-t

Normally when we write:

```
int a = 10;
int* ptr = &a;
std::cout << *ptr;
```

Code output is:

```
> 10
```

But when I write this:

```
const wchar_t* str = L"This is a simple text!";
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
std::wcout << &str << std::endl;
```

Code output is:

```
> This is a simple text!
> 012FFC0C
```

So this makes me confused.

- Doesn't that Asterisk symbol stand for pointer?
- If it is a pointer, how is it possible for us to assign a value other
  than the address value?
- Shouldn't the top output be at the bottom and
  the bottom output at the top?

Comment: `Doesn't that Asterisk symbol stand for pointer?` Yes. `If it is a pointer, how is it possible for us to assign a value other than the address value?` Huh?

Comment: `str` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `const wchar_t`. `T* p = some_array;` is equivalent to `T* p = &some_array[0];`. You should probably get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Yes it is a pointer. Normally when we write, ehr no I don't... I always try to minimize the use of (raw) pointers in C++.  For strings I use std::string (or std::string_view) for constant strings I use `static constexpr std::wstring{L"This is a simple text"};`.  (C++20, wide character string). 
More pointers on pointers use can be found in this document : Guidelines/CppCoreGuidelines (have a look at std::unique_ptr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L"This is a simple text!"` is an array of type `const wchar_t[23]` containing all the string characters plus a terminating 0 char. Arrays can decay in which case they turn into a pointer to the first element in the array which is what happens in

```
const wchar_t* str = L"This is a simple text!";
```

`std::wout` can be used with a `<<` operator that takes such a null terminated character as second operand; this operator prints the string.

The second print simply prints the address of the pointer, since there is no overload for the `<<` operator handling an argument of type `const wchar_t**` differently to arbitrary pointer types (except for some specific pointer types as seen in the first print).